# IRI node syncing very slowly

Tags: iri-node

I am running full headless node. The problem is that the syncing process is taking very long.

Being very optimistic it will take about one month.

What can be wrong?

Node specs:
- Core 2 duo 4 GB 650 GB
- Good broadband 
- Running linux headless Version 1.4.1.6 node 24/7

EDIT:
I know other person who suffers same issue
We had previous IRI version compiled from dev branch previously and it was performing better.
I am testing now if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the db.  Try this https://forum.iota.org/t/hourly-backup-of-iri-database-download-link/527

Comment: Yeach I have seen this too but its says:
Database zip file is updated again! 24/09 - so quite old.
I have used database from somebody elese but still my index is 32245

Comment: Deleting out the current database, putting in the new files, and restarting IRI doesn't help at all?  Then I don't know.  If you want files from today feel free to use this: http://iota.glass/sstfiles.tar.gz

Comment: Cool - Today is much better than I have now

Comment: Thanx - that solves problem - i will be able to finish sync much faster. Updating now.

Comment: I am doing something wrong or this file is not proper. Extracted files are much smaller ten ones that I have. 15GB vs 7GB and iri is crashing when I use them.

Comment: OK, I put up whole mainnetdb directory here: iota.glass/mainnetdb.tar.gz.  Uncompressed it should come out to about 7GB and works fine for me.  I also checked the validity of the file using gunzip -c mainnetdb.tar.gz | tar t > /dev/null and everything works out.  My DB was larger to when I did not fully sync but I used another database download which was smaller and everything worked out fine.  Give it another try and let us know.  Move your mainnetdb to another folder as backup and completely use the this new directory.